# Which function is this address pointing to?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

I am debugging an open source library that has a structure that gets initialized on load. One of the struct's members is a function pointer. What is the quickest way to figure to which function it is pointing to? For example, if I print out the value of the function pointer, is there some tool that I can use to find the name of the function? I am doing this on an embedded Linux system and GDB is not available (yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker can output a map file.  Assuming your functions don't move around, you can look up the address in there.  The option to produce the map file can vary; on my Mac it's [`-map`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html), the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) says it's `-Map`.

As a bit of an editorial aside, if you don't have a working source-level debugging solution, the *first* thing you should do is get one.  Stop all other work until you have a suitable infrastructure for development.  You might have to fight to convince your management that it's important, but hopefully you can make them understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the [addr2line command](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/addr2line.html#addr2line) useful.

Comment: The address I have is a function in a shared library. I am guessing I need to get the base address of the library and subtract that from the pointer. What's the easiest way to get the base address of a shared library?

Comment: Have you tried addr2line?  It should chase the shared library referenced by the executable and come up with an answer...